# Equivalent of deprecated jQuery Toggle Event

Tags: toggle, jquery

jQuery's [Toggle Event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function has [been removed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfntogglehandler-handler-is-deprecated) as part of version 1.9.

I was using this function like so:

```
$('#example').toggle(function() {
    do stuff
}, function() {
    do stuff
});
```

What would be the best way to reproduce this functionality now Toggle Event has gone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Load the MIGRATE and see the code there

See my post about the same thing

[Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone)

I have suggested they rename it to **fn.toggler** instead of removing it

Here is the code - it is a self-contained jQuery plugin and can be used as is.

```
jQuery.fn.toggle = function( fn, fn2 ) {
  // Don't mess with animation or css toggles
  if ( !jQuery.isFunction( fn ) || !jQuery.isFunction( fn2 ) ) {
    return oldToggle.apply( this, arguments );
  }
  // migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.toggle(handler, handler...) is deprecated");
  // Save reference to arguments for access in closure
  var args = arguments,
  guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++,
  i = 0,
  toggler = function( event ) {
    // Figure out which function to execute
    var lastToggle = ( jQuery._data( this, "lastToggle" + fn.guid ) || 0 ) % i;
    jQuery._data( this, "lastToggle" + fn.guid, lastToggle + 1 );
    // Make sure that clicks stop
    event.preventDefault();
    // and execute the function
    return args[ lastToggle ].apply( this, arguments ) || false;
  };
  // link all the functions, so any of them can unbind this click handler
  toggler.guid = guid;
  while ( i < args.length ) {
    args[ i++ ].guid = guid;
  }
  return this.click( toggler );
};
```

Shorter, non-tested version:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.toggler = function( fn, fn2 ) {
    var args = arguments,guid = fn.guid || $.guid++,i=0,
    toggler = function( event ) {
      var lastToggle = ( $._data( this, "lastToggle" + fn.guid ) || 0 ) % i;
      $._data( this, "lastToggle" + fn.guid, lastToggle + 1 );
      event.preventDefault();
      return args[ lastToggle ].apply( this, arguments ) || false;
    };
    toggler.guid = guid;
    while ( i < args.length ) {
      args[ i++ ].guid = guid;
    }
    return this.click( toggler );
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I already used the [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) plugin to determine that this function has been removed (it wasn't documented very well) but I'd rather not leave this plugin in as a solution. What would be a good equivalent?

Comment: Add the above code to your scripts. it is a plugin in its own right

Comment: I'm surprised there's not a more concise way of reproducing this functionality. Thanks though!

Comment: If you rename the function and remove the test for other toggle and  comments you have only a few lines of code

Comment: Fair enough. Marked as answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

This also works well.

```
$.fn.toggleClick = function(){

    var functions = arguments ;

    return this.click(function(){
            var iteration = $(this).data('iteration') || 0;
            functions[iteration].apply(this, arguments);
            iteration = (iteration + 1) % functions.length ;
            $(this).data('iteration', iteration);
    });
};
```