# jQuery ajax switch back to clicked img src

Tags: jquery, ajax, thumbnails

I have a enlarge image from thumb to large by ajax using click.

they using the same html elements just replace the img src
for example:

```
src="image_thumb.jpg"
```

switch to

```
src="image_large.jpg"
```

My question is, how to switch back to the thumb image when the user clicks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `toggle` is deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9, you should do this

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.data('originalSrc')){
    $this.prop('src', $this.data('originalSrc'));
    $.removeData(this, 'originalSrc');
  } else {
    $this.data('originalSrc', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.prop('src', 'image_large.jpg');
  }
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/PSFeJ/

Comment: This works, but can you explain $(this) and var $this = $(this) ?

Comment: inside the event callback, `this` refers to the DOM element. so, you want to "jqueryfy" your DOM element to manipulate it, that's the reason for `$this`. even though jQuery caches multiple calls to the same DOM element, it's of good practice to always assign your jquery object with a set of elements to a variable if you are going to perform multiple operations on it

Comment: I always using for example $('img'). Thanks for explaination.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) API to use two functions: one to change from thumb to large, the other to change from large to thumb. By using toggle, it will alternate between the two each time the user clicks.

If you want to try the class method, you can do this:

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass('thumb')){
     $(this).removeClass('thumb').addClass('large');
     //set your large image here
   } else {
     $(this).removeClass('large').addClass('thumb');
     //set your thumb image here
   }
});
```

The bonus here is that you can use CSS to make any changes to accommodate the large image or thumbnail.

Comment: Toggle is the way to go. In the first callback, get the image using AJAX, and in the second, replace it with the thumb's src.

Comment: I just check out the .toggle() and it says deprecated in 1.8 and will be removed in 1.9. Any replacement for .toggle() ?

Comment: Looks like there's nothing: [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338078/equivalent-of-deprecated-jquery-toggle-event)

Comment: just check it in click event

Comment: yea, the other option would be to [add a class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to the img tag like "thumb", and when you change it to the large image, [remove](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) the thumb class and add another class like "large". Then you can just check if it [has a class](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) and change it accordingly.