# jQuery : Use an alternative to .toggle() which is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images with class name ".mute_btn" and when i click on them, my images source is changing :

```
$('.mute_btn').toggle(function () {
        var clicked = false;
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        src = src.replace(/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1-over.$2");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    }, function () {
      var src = $(this).attr("src");
      src = src.replace(/(.*)-over\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1.$2");
      $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
```

But i've seen that toggle() is deprecated in jQuery 1.8

So i'm trying to do it like this :

```
var clicked = false;
$('.mute_btn').click(function() {
        if (clicked) {

            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            src = src.replace(/(.*)-over\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1.$2");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
            clicked = false;
        }
        else {
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            src = src.replace(/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1-over.$2");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
            clicked = true;
        }});
```

But the result is not perfect. Sometime, the images do not change state.

Do you know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/inutiw/5/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.mute_btn').click(function () {

      var src = this.src;
      var isClicked = src.indexOf('-over') > -1 ; // true if '-over' is found

      if( isClicked ){
          this.src = src.replace(/(.*)-over\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1.$2");    
      }else{
          this.src = src.replace(/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1-over.$2");
      }

});
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO using ternary operator](http://jsbin.com/inutiw/6/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.mute_btn').click(function () {

      var src = this.src;
      var isClicked = src.indexOf('-over') > -1 ;  
      this.src = isClicked ?
         src.replace(/(.*)-over\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1.$2") :
         src.replace(/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1-over.$2") ;

});
```

Comment: I like the way you find if isClicked is false or true. Smart !

Comment: Nice, except I would remove the last line and just say `this.src = ...` inside the if and the else blocks.

Comment: @nnnnnn was thinking about that. good idea. Actually better idea.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem is that you have multiple images, but you're trying to manage their clicked status with a single variable. Try storing the clicked status against the individual elements as follows:

```
$('.mute_btn').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data("clicked")) {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        src = src.replace(/(.*)-over\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1.$2");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
        $(this).data("clicked",false);
    }
    else {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        src = src.replace(/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1-over.$2");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
        $(this).data("clicked",true);
    }
});
```

Note that you could cache your `$(this)` object instead of making a new one each time, but I've not done so so that the change needed to solve your problem is more obvious.

Comment: How can I cache $(this) object ?

Comment: `var $this = $(this);` like this any variable name you like.

Comment: You can also chain jQuery methods, e.g., `$(this).attr("src",src).data("clicked",true);`. Or rework the whole thing a bit as per roXon's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the MIGRATE code available from jQuery

Have a look here for more on the same: [Equivalent of deprecated jQuery Toggle Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338078/equivalent-of-deprecated-jquery-toggle-event/14478259#14478259)

Answer (score 1):

The code that I use:

```
$('#example').click(function()
    {
    isClicked=$(this).data('clicked');
    if (isClicked) {isClicked=false;} else {isClicked=true;}
    $(this).data('clicked',isClicked);

    if(isClicked)
        {
        ...do stuff...
        }
    else
        {
        ...do stuff...
        }
    });
```