# Jquery toggle event toggles visibility instead

Tags: jquery, toggle

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#help').toggle(function () {
  $('#center').animate({
    paddingTop: '70px'
  }, 200);
  $('.child_help').slideDown(300);
}, function () {
  $('#center').animate({
    paddingTop: '50px'
  }, 200);
  $('.child_help').slideUp(300);
});
```

When I load the page, it instead toggles the visibility of `#help`. What I want to do is when you click it, it should slide `.child_help` either up or down, and do some padding animations.
On the jQuery API, it only says this:
`Note: jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.`

The only difference that I can see between what would fire the event, or toggle the visibility, is if it's `$('#help').toggle(function () { do something here })`, instead of `$('#help').toggle('slow');`

Is there something I'm missing here?

Edit: The following is my HTML

```
<div id="center">
  <div class="child_help">
    some help text here
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <b>Account Activation</b>
    <img src="/css/images/help.png" alt="" id="help" />
  </div>
  <form method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="code" value="Code" class="code" />
    <span class="case">Case-sensitive</span>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Activate" class="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: the toggle event handler was deprecated in 1.8 and has been removed in 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: if you're using a newer version of jquery, this toggle method will not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338078/equivalent-of-deprecated-jquery-toggle-event

Comment: Oh, thanks. They should say that on the jquery API.

Comment: @chrinsen it does at the very top header.. it says version deprecated 1.8, removed 1.9..  What you can do is bind it to a click handler and do your animations there

Comment: @wirey Oh, didn't see that. So small text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9x6Vx/1/)

```
$(function(){
  $("#help").click(function(){
     var padding="70px";
     if($(".child_help").css("display")=="none") padding="50px";

     $('#center').animate({
         paddingTop: padding
     }, 200);

     $(".child_help").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: The only reason I didn't use that was because I want to animate some css too. But other than that, this would work.

Comment: I added the css animations you have in your question.