# convert hover to click event for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to convert a hover event for a degraded jquery flip piece of my script.  I've done this for the css3d transform but I'm not sure how to convert the hover event for the degraded portion.  Here is what I have so far:

```
if($("html").hasClass("csstransforms3d")){

    $('.card').click(function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('flip')) {
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('flip');
        }
    });

    /*
    $('.card').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('flip');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('flip');
    });
    */
} 
else{
    // How do I add a click event here instead of hover?
    $('.card').hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".front").animate({top: -190}, 'fast');
    },function(){
        $(this).find(".front").animate({top: 0}, 'fast');
    });
}
```

How do I convert the hover event for a click event for the degraded section?

Comment: replace the word hover with click?

Comment: didn't you mean `mousedown` and `mouseup`?

Comment: replace 'hover' with 'click'

Comment: @raam86 no, won't work like this.

Comment: @raam86 because both callbacks will be called at once. OP is looking for toggle() event, i think, which is now removed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338078/equivalent-of-deprecated-jquery-toggle-event

Comment: @MightyPork Can't I call a click event like I did for the css3d portion?

Comment: All I want to do is replace the hover event with a click event if possible

Comment: hover has two states - mouseover and mouseout. Click is stateless.

Comment: @raam86 just tested, in fact, only last callback is called

Comment: @roasted nice one. Missed the `,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use click, you need to store a state value - you can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) to do it

Try something like

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.data('hidden')){
        $this.find(".front").animate({top: -190}, 'fast').data('hidden', false);
    } else {
        $this.find(".front").animate({top: 0}, 'fast').data('hidden', true);
    }

});
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution but for some reason the data attribute isn't getting set...any thoughts?

Comment: I ended up setting the data attribute first and then checking the state but it's working...Thanks!