# is(':hidden') always false after slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am unable to detect slide up/down of the `slideToggle()` function of jQuery.
I have used this article for reference [Demo of slideToggle in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657230/slidetoggle-can-detect-slideup-or-slidedown)

```js
$('#ToogleMe').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#toogleResult').slideToggle();
  var check = $('#toogleResult').is(':hidden');
  if (check == true) {
    console.log('up');
  } else {
    console.log('down');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="ToogleMe" value="Toogle" />
<div id="toogleResult">Random Message</div>
```

`#toogleResult` is being toggled successfully however the var `check` is always `false`. Why is this?

**Image of my Output**

[image: Image of my Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this you need to execute your code within the `callback` parameter of the `slideToggle()` method. This ensures it runs after the animation has completed and the element is in its final state. Try this:

```js
$('#ToogleMe').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#toogleResult').slideToggle(function() {
    var check = $('#toogleResult').is(':hidden');
    if (check) {
      console.log('up');
    } else {
      console.log('down');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="ToogleMe" value="Toogle" />
<div id="toogleResult">Random Message</div>
```