# JQuery: toggle css properties on/off

Tags: jquery, html, css, properties, toggle

With my website I'm trying to do some JQuery which I thought would be simple (as a beginner):

- Click a div/button in a news header.
- As a result, have the image in it rotate/replaced (arrow).
- As a result, create a scrollbar in the div below the header.
- Click the div/button again and it toggles back to its original position.

I've managed to make things work, but only with two separate divs/arrows, this in the following manner:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scroll').css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', function() {
        $('.news-section-links-internal-1').css({
            overflow: 'scroll',
            marginRight: '0px',
            width: '230px',
            paddingRight: '15px'
        }); 
    });

    $('.noscroll').css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', function() {
        $('.news-section-links-internal-1').css({
            overflow: 'hidden',
            marginRight: '15px',
            width: '225px',
            paddingRight: '0px'
        });               
    }); 
});
```

It looks a little crude though, so I've been trying to combine this code so it works with one toggle div/button based on tips found on Stackoverflow. Below is an example of that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scroll").css('cursor', 'pointer').toggle( function() {
        $('.news-section-links-internal-1').css({             
            overflow: 'scroll',
            marginRight: '0px',
            width: '230px',
            paddingRight: '15px'
        });
    }, function () {
        $('.news-section-links-internal-1').css({            
            overflow: 'hidden',
            marginRight: '15px',
            width: '225px',
            paddingRight: '0px'
        });
    }); 
});
```

Unfortunately, the combined code never works. In the above example the toggle div/button simply fades out when I load the page and that's it.

Can anyone help me with this problem? I don't need a whole lot of JQuery on my page, but this is quite crucial. Been trying for two days.

If it helps, here's all the relevant CSS:

```
.news-section-links {
    background-color: #fffffc;
    width: 245px !important;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.news-section-links-internal-1 {
    width: 225px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fffffc;
    margin-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the html code as well?

Comment: hi now you can create a class and used to toggle Class

Comment: `toggle()` event method has been removed from jQuery 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ Use click event instead  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338078/equivalent-of-deprecated-jquery-toggle-event

Comment: it's working http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/crvcevoh/

Comment: @RohitAzad It is no more working http://jsfiddle.net/crvcevoh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hi now  you  can try to `toggleClass`  as like this .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scroll").on('click', function(){
        $('.news-section-links-internal-1').toggleClass('class-1');
    });     
});
```

```css
.class{
    overflow:hidden;
            margin-right: 15px;
            width: 225px;
            padding-right: 0;
}
.class-1.class{
            margin-right: 0;
            width: 230px;
            padding-right: 15px;
    overflow:scroll;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-section-links-internal-1 class">This is Demo text This is Demo text This is Demo text This is Demo text This is Demo text This is Demo text This is Demo text This is Demo text </div>


<button class="scroll">Click here for result</button>
```

> more info **[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**

Comment: Seriously, how do I reply when I can't hit the enter button to go down a line? *working on that issue*