# Jquery: Adding .toggle to <a> makes it disappear

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I have

```
<a id="autoUpdate">Auto-Update: ON</a>
```

and

```
$('#autoUpdate').toggle(function(){
alert('a');
}, function(){
alert('b');
})
```

When the page loads, the complete `<a>`-Tag gets display:none and 'b' is alerted! 
I should add that this is site in developing stage using Twitter Bootstrap if that matters and the link is in the top-navigation.
Btw, if I change the a-tag to a `<p>` f.e. everything seems fine.

Comment: Something else is causing your problem as the above code does not have any issues.  See this example... http://jsfiddle.net/ELr5F/1/

Comment: what is the error showing in the firebug console. here the code is working.there might be some other errors.!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone)

Answer (score 11):

You're using the deprecated `.toggle` function. It's removed in jQuery >= 1.9.0, so if you're using that version this code will invoke the `.toggle` animation function instead, where the second function is the callback (and will be executed immediately in this case).

Instead, you should implement such functionality yourself:

```
var toggleState = true;
$('#autoUpdate').on("click", function() {
  if(toggleState) {
    alert('a');
  } else {
    alert('b');
  }
  toggleState = !toggleState;
});
```