# Toggle stopped working after jquery update

Tags: jquery, toggle

I was using jquery 1.3 on my website. Today I updated it to newest 1.9 and my toggle/animate script stopped to work.

The code looks like that:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" id="toggler">Show more</a>
<div id="tcontent"> … </div>

$(document).ready(function() {                      
    $('#toggler').toggle(
    function() {
        $('#tcontent').animate({height: "70"}, 800);
    },
    function() {
        $('#tcontent').animate({height: "6"}, 800);
    });
});
```

What is wrong with this code? When I include back jquery 1.3 to my html everything works fine.

Comment: I happened to answer this 10 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603775/jquery-adding-toggle-to-a-makes-it-disappear/14603971#14603971.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="#" id="toggler" data-show="no">Show more</a>
```

and

```
$(function() {                      
  $('#toggler').on("click",function(e) {
      if ($(this).data("show")=="no") {
        $('#tcontent').animate({height: "70"}, 800);
        $(this).data("show","yes");
      }   
      else {
        $('#tcontent').animate({height: "6"}, 800);
        $(this).data("show","no");     
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggler').click( function() {
    $('#tcontent').toggle(
        function()
        {
            $(this).animate({height: "70"}, 800);
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).animate({height: "6"}, 800);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: toggle event has been deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9

Comment: Good spot... should have tested this a bit more before I posted!

Comment: I know because I asked myself the same question 2 weeks ago :)