# Jquery .toggle replacement code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have (had) a button on my website that switched between a wide and narrow layout for articles. Since JQuery 1.9, this hasn't worked because of the deprecation of toggle. I'm no great whizz at JS, and haven't managed to cobble together an answer from the various questions on here, so would like someone to look at my specific case if possible. I appreciate that for someone more competent this is probably very obvious, but I'm still learning!

The site is here, e.g:

http://www.davidsmith.name/2011/09/04/Real-surreal-and-hyperreal-in-crash-and-the-beach/

Applicable part of code as follows:

```
<span><a id="switch" href="#" title="switch the menu"><span id="blogview">Switch to Article View</span>
 <span id="articleview" class="hide">Switch to Blog View</span></a></span><br/>
 <span id="readability" class="hide"><span class="rdbWrapper" data-show-read="1" data-show-send-to-kindle="1" data-show-print="1" data-show-email="0" data-orientation="0" data-version="1" data-bg-color="transparent"></span><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],rdb = document.createElement("script"); rdb.type = "text/javascript"; rdb.async = true; rdb.src = document.location.protocol + "//www.readability.com/embed.js"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(rdb, s); })();</script></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $('a#switch').(function () {
            $('div#right').hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
            $('div#left').delay(300).animate({width: 950}, 600);
            $('span#blogview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#articleview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#readability').toggleClass('hide');
            }, function () {
            $('div#right').delay(500).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
            $('div#left').animate({width: 430}, 500);
            $('span#blogview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#articleview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#readability').toggleClass('hide');}
            );
</script><br />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14604538/295783)

which would translate to

```
$(function() {                      
   $('a#switch').on("click",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).data("show")=="no") {
            $('div#right').hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
            $('div#left').delay(300).animate({width: 950}, 600);
            $('span#blogview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#articleview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#readability').toggleClass('hide');
        $(this).data("show","yes");
      }   
      else {
            $('div#right').delay(500).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
            $('div#left').animate({width: 430}, 500);
            $('span#blogview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#articleview').toggleClass('hide');
            $('span#readability').toggleClass('hide');
        $(this).data("show","no");     
      }
  });
});
```