# jQuery UI slide direction issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm adding a slide menu effect to my site using jQuery UI, but I'm having a small and very odd issue. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menuitem").hide();
    var url = window.location;
    $('.menulink').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).removeClass('menulink');
    $($(".menuitem").get().reverse()).each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).delay(i*400).toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

Adding ", { direction: "left" }" after the "slide" makes the element appear instead of sliding.

Could it be my implementation of jQuery UI? This is the code I'm using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
$($(".menuitem").get().reverse()).each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).delay(i*400).toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000);
    });
```

**FYI**: The `toggle()` method was deprecated in jQuery **version 1.8**, and removed in **version 1.9**.

Here is a SO question regarding [toggle replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626335/jquery-toggle-replacement-code) and for more slide tutorial you can try this [link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't work. Are my versions for jquery and jqueryui correct?

Comment: @Flaxbeard that right, your Jquery version does not support `toggle()`.  [http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js) this should work.

Comment: Ah... Toggle itself works fine though, even though it's depreciated? What can I use instead? The toggle works, but instead of sliding from the left, it's from the top-left, and adding direction: 'left' breaks it entirely.

Comment: @Flaxbeard I would suggest `animate()`

Comment: Does animate() work with slide left? (Also, does the google library have the slide function?)

Comment: Animate won't work for what I need. The elements have a position, and I want them to slide to it in a certain order, like what toggle slide does but only from the left.

Comment: The only issue is that the items are hidden and when they slide they bump the previous one up. How can I fix this? With just plain toggle slide on my site (not on jSfiddle) it doesn't do that...

Comment: The example here (without jQueryUI) Seems to work, oddly enough. http://jsfiddle.net/Pxrvx/

Comment: @Flaxbeard I'm not sure whether you're trying this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/gsx4v/)