# How can I toggle style(s) of a class?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list of paragraphs in a chatbox:

```
<div id=chatbox>
    <p><i>15:21</i><b data-c=john>john</b>: hello jack</p>
    <p><i>15:22</i>i want to tell you something</p>
    <p><i>17:17</i><b data-c=jack>jack</b>: hi john.</p>
    <p class=hidden><i>20:15</i>Ο <span data-c=server>server</span> alex joined the chat</p>
    <p><i>17:17</i><b data-c=alex>alex</b>: hi all of you.</p>
</div>
```

and I want to have a toggle button in order to show/hide the hidden elements. Is there a way to toggle the style of `hidden` class from `display:none` to `display:inline` and backwards?

Notice that if i change all existing class=hidden to visible, when AJAX brings a new hidden line, it will still be hidden in contrast with previous elements. Is there a way to change the content of a class style?

Comment: nwalton's answer below is the way to go, since you can't directly edit the content of a CSS rule. That answer works in your added case, with AJAX bringing in new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a really bad idea to make javascript iterate through all of the elements to change the display when you can do it really easily by just toggling a class on a parent element.

[Here's the codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lcLfz)

When the button is clicked, you can just toggle a `showHidden` class on the `#chatbox` element, and use CSS to hide or display all of the hidden items inside it.

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#chatbox.showHidden .hidden {
  display: inline;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $('.toggleButton').on('click', function(){
    $('#chatbox').toggleClass('showHidden');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a button

```
<div id=chatbox>
    <p><i>15:21</i><b data-c=john>john</b>: hello jack</p>
    <p><i>15:22</i>i want to tell you something</p>
    <p><i>17:17</i><b data-c=jack>jack</b>: hi john.</p>
    <p class=hidden><i>20:15</i>Ο <span data-c=server>server</span> alex joined the chat</p>
    <p><i>17:17</i><b data-c=alex>alex</b>: hi all of you.</p>
</div>
<button id="show_hidden">Show Hidden</button>
```

change the style for that class, and any future elements with that class

```
var button = document.getElementById('show_hidden'),
    hidden = true;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var st = document.getElementById('myStyle');

    if (st) {
        st.innerHTML = '.hidden { display: '+ (hidden?'block':'none') +'; }';
    }else{
        var css = '.hidden { display: block; }',
            head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            style = document.createElement('style');

        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.id   = 'myStyle';

        if (style.styleSheet){
            style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
            style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }
        head.appendChild(style);
    }

    button.innerHTML = (hidden ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
    hidden = !hidden;
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SKUzQ/1/)

Comment: Yes, but if i change all class=hidden to display:block, when AJAX brings a new hidden line, it will still be hidden in contrast with previous elements. Is there a way to change the content of a class style?

Comment: This is probably more complicated than it needs to be. A simple style sheet rule removes the need for most of the javascript.

Comment: @nwalton - You're right, I just undeleted the answer to show how to use javascript to change the style for a class, also for future elements, as that was the question, even if attaching the styles to a parent element solves this in a much nicer way.

Answer (score -1):

if using jquery look up `.toggle`  here http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

also see here for javascript only answer: [Jquery .toggle replacement code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626335/jquery-toggle-replacement-code)