# Logic of using jQuery .one

Tags: javascript, optimization, jquery

Using jQuery's [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler to do a setup on the first click and something else on the next/subsequent clicks, is it possible to do write this more elegantly:

```
$('#start').one('click', function(){
    alert('one');

    // could also be .on for subsequent clicks
    $(this).one('click', function(){
        alert('two');    
    });

});
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjHXb/)

**Update**: I was hoping that there was a jQuery pattern to using .one
like this [self-defining function](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Zyy/1/),
but reading [the source for .one()](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.one) it's just an extension of .on()

Comment: You might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com for optimization of working code.

Comment: Perhaps you mean this deprecated function which you can reinstate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks for that, I wasn't really even aware of the code review site though I wonder how much of SO belongs there.

Comment: @lucuma It's still in beta and obviously doesn't have the audience SO has, but if people don't know about it, it never will.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link to codereview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clickIndex = 0;
$('#start').on('click', function(){
    alert(++clickIndex);
});
```

you could put a `switch` statement or an `if` block in here to run different code depending on how many times the user has clicked. If the `.one` listener unbinding is key for you, simply use `.off` when `clickIndex` indicates you are done with the binding.

Comment: True, but I was wondering if there was a jQuery logic attached to the .one method. If not, the method almost seems pointless ( you could just use .on() and then off() instead of .one() )

Comment: `.one` is literally just a shorthand for `.on` and `.off`

Comment: It does have a point, but very limited point. Personally, it a shorthand I suspect most people rarely use.

Comment: The function that I wrote above could also be reworked to be a recursive function with `.one` but it would just be harder to read and kinda pointless compared with whats there now.

Comment: Read my update. If nothing else comes along, this is clearly the best, simple solution. Was hoping that .one() was meant to be used for other purposes other than the obvious (!).

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you could just use a data property or class and use the click event:

```
$('#start').on('click', function(){
    if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
      alert('one');
      $(this).data('clicked', 'true');
    }
    else  {
      alert('more than one');
    }
});
```

or with a class:

```
$('#start').on('click', function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      alert('one');
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }
    else  {
      alert('more than one');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why `jQuery.data`? A local variable is so much simpler.

Comment: It really just depends on what the OP wants.  On many projects that have rich interfaces there would be some kind of styling based on this condition and the class solution is generally what I'd use.  A local variable works but may not be ideal in all cases either.

Comment: @mplungjan it is matter of opinion and probably would be implementation Dependant as to what is simpler.  Eliminating a call to jquery in a simplistic example is one thing but combining something in the framework of a web app it might not be  simple to track a lot of local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
$('#start').on('click', function(){
    var click = $(this).data('clicked')?$(this).data('clicked'):1;
    alert(click);
    if(click === 2)
        $(this).off('click')
    else $(this).data('clicked',++click);    
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `jQuery.data`? A local variable is so much simpler.