# Jquery toggle animation On click

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, toggle

I am trying to expand a div on click, and on another click shrink it again. 
When this function is called, nothing happens.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(".panel").toggle(function()
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({width:'300px',height:'300px'}, 200);
    });
},
function()
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({width:'152px',height:'152px'}, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone)

Comment: What version of JQuery? Also, make a jsbin with some more code in it

Comment: If possible can you provide html code as well?

Comment: a solution is remove `$(this).click(function()`, but better read about toggle deprecation

Comment: Why do you have `.click()` nested in the toggle?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that toggle deprecation, but it is relevant.

Comment: @j08691 This isn't a duplicate really. This is wanting a means to an end, without specifying they are requiring the use of .toggle

Comment: @JClaspill - the question I linked to discusses how the use of the `toggle()` methods has been removed from jQuery and an alternate way to simulate the same functionality.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, it is a valid link to provide as a reference for not using toggle in this instance. But this question isn't a duplicate, which is what you flagged it as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

toggle() only hides and displays the div, and it does not take in two functions as parameters.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Here is my solution to this, although I am not sure if this is the best, hope someone would point out improvements.

```
var next_move = "expand";
$(document).ready(function (){
$(".panel").click(function()
{
    var css = {};
    if (next_move == "expand"){
        css = {
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px'
        };
        next_move = "shrink";
    } else {
        css = {
            width: '152px',
            height: '152px'
        };     
        next_move = "expand";
    }
    $(this).animate(css, 200);
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vc49G/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

`click()` is not neccesary inside toggle functions, try this:

```
$(".panel").toggle(
function()
{
    $(this).animate({width:'300px',height:'300px'}, 200);
},
function()
{
    $(this).animate({width:'152px',height:'152px'}, 200);
}
);
```

By the way, [this method was deprecated in jquery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)

Comment: Sorry I'm using 1.9.2, so it doesn't work for me, but thanks anyway :)