# Why is jquery toggle not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I simply want to have a variable toggle between true and false and have the text on the `button` clicked to change as well. Here is my Jquery:

```
$("button").toggle(
  function () {
    $(this).text("Click to change to paint brush");
      var erasing = true;
  },
  function () {
    $(this).text("Click to change to eraser");
      var erasing = false;
  }
);
```

This looks 100% sound to me, but in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymeYv/1/) you will see that it is toggling the existence of the button before I can even click it! **Why is this happening and how can I fix it?**

Comment: That toggle version was changed in jquery 1.8 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version of toggle has been deprecated (1.8) and removed (1.9). Now you need to handle it in button click itself. 
Somthing like this:

```
var erasing = false;
$("button").click(function () {
    erasing = !erasing;
      $(this).text(function (_, curText) {
          return curText == "Click to change to paint brush" ? "Click to change to eraser" :  "Click to change to paint brush" ;
      });
    console.log(erasing);
  });
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hMda/)

Plus if you want to preserve the value of the variable just define them out of the click event scope, so that it is more global to be accessed outside.

See

- **[.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**
- **[.text(func) syntax](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text)**
- **[Deprecated toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)**

Comment: This works 3 times...I solved the problem with an if statement once you said that toggle doesn't work

Comment: @RyanSaxe Thats because of a typo.. Eraser in the code. :) Its in your code as well.

Comment: @RyanSaxe yes thats because of the logic. If you invert the condition it will still work.

Comment: Yes, I like your method...even though I posted a solution that works, this is a good way.

Comment: @RyanSaxe See my update; ditch all those variables, conditions. You can use ! to invert boolean and text's function to flip the button text.

Comment: I see. I will mark your answer as correct then as it is more efficient than mine

Comment: I'd wrap that whole thing in a closure to prevent that `erasing` variable from going global.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for explaining how toggle is out of date...so that is all I needed and then I solved my problem with a simple `if` statement:

```
var erasing = false;
var i = 0
$("button").click(function () {
    if(i%2==0){
        $(this).text("Click to change to paint brush");
        erasing = true;
    }
    else{
        $(this).text("Click to change to eraser");
        erasing = false;
    };
    i += 1
  });
```

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymeYv/7/)

Answer (score 0):

As PSL said, the `toggle` you're looking for [is gone and lost](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed). if you want a click and hold solution (as your title suggests), you could look at using `mouseup` and `mousedown`.

```
 var erasing;
 $("button").on({
    "mousedown": function () {
        $(this).text("Click to change to paint brush");
        erasing = true;
    },
    "mouseup mouseleave": function () {
        $(this).text("Click to change to eraser");
        erasing = false;
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/ymeYv/6/

Comment: This does not work because it does not toggle between them on click. Also, the hold thing was for a different question, I must have been in the wrong tab