# Jquery "toggle" method is behaving wierdly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a chunk of code like this:

```
$(".ani-search").toggle(
    function(){
        $("#header .logo a").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=30px",
            marginLeft: "-=60px",
            marginLeft: "-=90px"
        });
    },

    function(){
        $("#header .logo a").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=60px",
            marginLeft: "-=30px",
            marginLeft: "0px"
      })
   }
);
```

When I run the corresponding html page, I do not get any VALID toggle response. What happens is as soon as I open the page the image with class "ani-search" blinks once and vanishes thats it, I do not get to toggle anything? Why is this happening?

Similarly here is another test code"

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.0.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>
    $("p").toggle(
        function(){
            alert("Cliclk 1");
        },
        function(){
            alert("Click 2");
        }
    );    
</script>
```

same thing happens here, as soon as I load the page in my browser, the text "Hello world" blinks once and I get the alert box with message with "Click 2". Thats it.

Why cant I toggle here?

Comment: This form of `toggle()` went away in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: thats bcos `toggle` is gone in jQ 1.10 versions

Comment: OMG!!!! Then what can I do, what is the alternative syntax?

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone) You can find advice on what to do there.

Comment: should I use the jquery migrate plugin or try the new toggle fnction

Comment: There is no new toggle function, it's just the old one that toggles visibility

Comment: I mean 'data'. Should I use this data or just use migrate.js?

Comment: If you need to support old code you include migrate, if your writing new code you write valid code and implement your own toggle, no need for migrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecated and removed, create your own toggle functionality :

```
$(".ani-search").on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).data('state')) {
        $("#header .logo a").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=30px",
            marginLeft: "-=60px",
            marginLeft: "-=90px"
        });
    }else{
        $("#header .logo a").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=60px",
            marginLeft: "-=30px",
            marginLeft: "0px"
        });
    }
    $(this).data('state', !$(this).data('state'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gXfeQ/1/)

note that adding the same CSS property multiple times does not animate it multiple times, only the last one is used.

Comment: Sorry I did not get the last line "Adding multiple css lines" what is that?

Comment: If you add marginLeft three times in the same object, it does not animate marginLeft three times

Comment: Oh, yeah its like that... sweet got it

Comment: @adeneo you did it wrong! you ddn't make an ajax redirect after the square reached the right! :P

Comment: @SpYk3HH - I was going to, then it struck me, I could just submit a form !

Answer (score 1):

`toggle` is gone. You might want to use `data` attribute to do this by yourself :

```
$("p").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).data("click")) {
        alert("Click 2");
        $(this).data("click", false);
    } else {
        alert("Cliclk 1");
        $(this).data("click", true);
    }
});
```