# jQuery toggle() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I know now .`toggle()` method is deprecated in jQuery version 1.9. It is ok, but I was familiar with it. The solution was to import the latest jQuery migrate plugin.

On the official jQuery API documentation I can see that there is a note in the description of the .toggle() method:

> ***Not recommended. Use .toggleClass() instead***

Yes, I may use `.toggleClass()` instead, but in this case it only switches between two classes.

Also, why is it not recommended to use?

Comment: You can easily create your own toggle() -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840644/jquery-toggle-method-is-behaving-wierdly/17840756#17840756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Not recommended. Use .toggleClass() instead" comment is about the provided example, which toggles a class using `.toggle()`, it's not a general comment about `.toggle()`.

The docs also state why it is not recommended to use:

> The .toggle() method is provided for convenience. It is relatively
>   straightforward to implement the same behavior by hand, and this can
>   be necessary if the assumptions built into .toggle() prove limiting.
>   For example, .toggle() is not guaranteed to work correctly if applied
>   twice to the same element. Since .toggle() internally uses a click
>   handler to do its work, we must unbind click to remove a behavior
>   attached with .toggle(), so other click handlers can be caught in the
>   crossfire. The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the
>   event, so links will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked
>   if .toggle() has been called on the element.

[See further discussion here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786)

Answer (score 0):

Because in future versions of jQuery `.toggle()` won't be there for you to call and will error out in your code.

Comment: Yes, it will, but as I've mentioned above I have a migrate plugin imported.

Comment: I was answering the only question that I saw.  If you have a question about toggleClass() I can try to answer that. :)