# Create a toggle function onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I'm trying to do a toggle function on click.
I don't understand why my function doesn't work, it's very simple...

http://jsfiddle.net/7y46W/1/

```
 $("#hello").toggle(function(){
 $('#content').css({marginLeft:'20px'});
     },function(){
 $('#content').css({marginLeft:'0px'});
 });
```

Comment: `.toggle` doesn't do that anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone)

Comment: Use Jquery 1.8 (before 1.9) in your fiddle and your code will work fine.

Comment: Thank you all, your answers are very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#hello").on('click', function(){
    var toggle = $(this).data('toggle');  // get current state

    $('#content').css('margin-left', toggle ? 0 : 20);

    $(this).data('toggle', !toggle);      // set state to opposite of current
});                                       // state, i.e. a toggle switch
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q45SP/1/)

Comment: A little explanation would help  !!

Comment: Should be self explanatory ?

Comment: Yes I did, to accommodate your request for an explaination ?

Answer (score 0):

it does work... when you include jQuery.
See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y46W/9/).

```
included jQuery in framework selector.
```