# JQuery .toggle method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript/JQuery code which should make the div `SideBar` appear on the screen and become 1/5th the size of the body. I'm getting no errors in Firefox/Chrome console, and havve no idea why it isn't working. If I move the body of my first toggle method into the method itself it works fine, so I'm assuming I'm using the toggle method wrong.

```
var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
sideWidth = bodyWidth / 5;

function slideSideBar() {
    $('#SideBar').toggle(
        function() {
            $("#SideBar").animate({
                opacity: 0.6,
                width: sideWidth
            }, 600);
        }, 
        function() {
            $("#SideBar").animate({
                opacity: 0,
                width: 0
            }, 600);
        });
}
```

The CSS is:

```
#SideBar { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
    color: white; 
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: How is `slideSideBar` called? and do you have the code in a dom ready handler ?

Comment: @karthikr I have a menu icon in my HTML code, which has the onclick event to call the function `slideSideBar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.8, the [`toggle` event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (the version of `toggle` that accepted two functions) was deprecated, and as of 1.9, it was removed. More in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone).

To get the old `toggle` behavior, maintain your own flag (or in your case, check the opacity) and call the [`toggle` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) (not event) yourself.

Here's the flag method, since it may be more appropriate to an `animate` situation (note the use of `stop`, which you probably wanted even in <=1.8):

```
var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
sideWidth = bodyWidth / 5;

function slideSideBar() {
    var sidebar = $("#SideBar");
    var flag = sidebar.css("opacity") != 0;

    sidebar.click(function() {
        var options = flag ? {opacity: 0, width: 0} : {opacity: 0.6, width: sideWidth};
        flag = !flag;
        sidebar.stop(true, true).animate(options, 600);
    });
}
```

Or actually, checking opacity is fine after the `stop`:

```
var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
sideWidth = bodyWidth / 5;

function slideSideBar() {
    $("#SideBar").click(function() {
        var sidebar = $(this);
        sidebar.stop(true, true);
        sidebar.animate(
            sidebar.css("opacity") != 0 ? {opacity: 0, width: 0} : {opacity: 0.6, width: sideWidth},
            600
        );
    });
}
```