# toggle() not working in jQuery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, versions

Why isn't this code working with jQuery 1.10.2, but with 1.8.3? 
Are there probably any minor changes to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mob-nav-overlay").hide();
    $(".mob-nav-button").show(); 
    $('.mob-nav-button').toggle(function() {
        $("#mob-nav-close").html("x");
        $(".mob-nav-overlay").fadeIn("fast");
    })},
    function() {
        $("#mob-nav-close").text("#");
        $(".mob-nav-overlay").fadeOut("fast");
    })
});
```

Thanks a lot! Paul

Comment: This would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.toggle()` event was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/