# jQuery.toggle - execute two or more handler on alternate clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button to switch on edit mode: show some `#edit_bar` and turns on `.selectable()`:

```
$('#edit_mode').click(function() {
  $('#edit_bar').slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $('#foo').selectable("enable");
  });
});
```

I wish to disable `.selectable()` when the button is clicked second time (turn off edit mode).

I'm wondering about best way to do that. There was `.toggle()` method to do so but it's replaced now by something very different.

- [Old toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (deprecated but would be perfect for what I need)
- [New toggle method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

How about setting a flag for this? It would set a toggle effect such that the flag will be checked each time the click function is called and will perform the appropriate function:

```
var flag = true;
$('#edit_mode').click(function() {
  $('#edit_bar').slideToggle("slow", function() {
  if(flag == true) {
       $('#foo').selectable("enable");
       flag = false;
    }
    else {
       $('#foo').selectable("disable");
       flag = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep, I know it can be done that way but I was expecting some ready to use old fassion `.toggle` replacement or some explanation why it's not longer available. I like Randy's answer for [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone) the most I think.