# jQuery: toggle functions on click, since toggle() is no longer available

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

If we have 2 functions we want to execute alternatively, one at `mouseover` and the other at `mouseout`, we can do that easily in jQuery:

```js
var firstFunc = function() {
  console.log("first");
}

var secondFunc = function() {
  console.log("second");
}

$('.class-name').hover(firstFunc, secondFunc);
```

```css
.class-name {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #069;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-name">Hover me</div>
```

Since the deprecation of `toggle()`, we can not use it to trigger the two functions alternatively, on `click` event.

In fact, I want to use both: `hover` on desktops and `click` on mobile devices.

Questions:

1. What shall we use instead?
2. What would be helpful if used in a manner similar to the `hover()` method, without the use of an if clause?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ "*It is relatively straightforward to implement the same behavior by hand*".

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150375/2181514

Comment: and: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+toggle+event

Comment: Since "I want to use both: hover on desktops and click on mobile devices", I believe my question is not a duplicate. It would be useful to post an answer with the exact solution I have applied.

Comment: You can't quietly change the question then say, "but I said this...".  You could say you've updated the question and don't believe that you have the skill to rework the provided answer to match your scenario.

Comment: Your edit **completely changes the question** - you might be better off asking a *new* question that includes *all* the details.

Answer (score -1):

Better way is to create separate events.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.class-name', function () {
    console.log("first");
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.class-name', function () {
    console.log("second");
});
```

Comment: Did you read the question?  It's about using `.toggle` - the `.hover` was just there as an example of how simple this could be (and to confuse everyone...)